# Ошибка клонирования в GitHub

Tags: git, ssh, github, git-clone

**При наборе:**

```
$ git clone https://tarasula@bitbucket.org/tarasula/firstrepo.git
```

**Выдает ошибку:**

> fatal: unable to access 'https://tarasula@bitbucket.org/tarasula/firstrepo.git': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org

Подскажите кто сталкивался.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с DNS.

А интернет на этой машине есть, можете проверить?

Comment: Да интернет есть.

Comment: Эта команда выводит ваш внешний IP?

`wget "https://archergodson.com" -q -O - | grep "REMOTE_ADDR" | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'`

Comment: Нет.
Пишет:

wget: command not found
-q: command not found
grep: invalid option -- o
...

Comment: это сложнее проверить для меня )) так.. как вы проверяете, что инет есть?

Comment: Возможно т.к. это рабочая машина.

Comment: Захожу в браузер и проверяю)
Но судя по вопросу чувствую что не правельно проверяю.

Comment: Наверняка тогда в браузере настроен прокси-сервер, точно такие же настройки нужно сделать и для git

Comment: Открывается страница https://bitbucket.org/ сайта

Comment: Как настроить прокси-сервер для git?

Comment: `git config --global https.proxy http://<username>:<password>@proxy-server:port`

Comment: А какой **password** должен быть?

Comment: Это должен знать ваш системный администратор или администратор того прокси-сервера, которым пользуетесь. Если "ломается интернет" и вы обращаетесь к какому-то человеку, то он точно знает, как вам помочь и в текущй проблеме.

Comment: На самом деле это нужно лично мне в свободное от работы время.
По этому все что касается этой темы могу либо гуглить либо спросить тут т.к. на работе занимаюсь другими вещами.

Comment: В любом случае понадобится узнать адрес и порт прокси-сервера, логин и пароль. Если вы его никогда не вводили в браузере, то скорее всего используются технологии авторизации из самой системы. Попробуйте использовать логин и пароль, который используется при входе в систему (включении компьютера).

Comment: в Firefox пожете попробовать набрать `about:config` и ввести в фильтр `network.proxy`.

Значения `network.proxy.ssl и network.proxy.ssl_port` - это адрес и порт прокси-сервера для протокола https

Comment: только пароль свой спрячьте маской ХХХХХХ, а так - да, выглядит синтаксически правильно. только `http://` перед `ANDREYO02`

Comment: Нет. Все равно та же ошибка :(
А может можно сделать наоборот?
Убрать прокси?
И как теперь посмотреть установлены ли параметры прокми на Git?

Comment: можно скачать не используя git, а браузером, вот тут описано, как можно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044749/bitbucket-download-source-as-zip

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Всё-таки советую под каким-нибудь предлогом узнать настройки прокси. Пригодится.